# Bean marked with @ConfigurationProperties not refreshing when RefreshEndpoint.refresh is called

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I have a bean defined using @ConfigurationProperties and reading the properties from GUI when someone updates the value on GUI of these properties I called RefreshEndpoint.refresh to refresh the properties of bean, it is a microservice architecture and the refresh method sends a message to all the Microservice which in turn calls the refresh method, the bean is updating in other microservices except the one

All MS has managemen endpoiunts refresh enabled and has a common configuration files unless some extra configuration specific to that Ms is required.

```
@Data

@Builder

@Component("gitConfig")

@NoArgsConstructor

@AllArgsConstructor

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "configmanagement.gitconfig")

@Scope(scopeName = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)

public class GitConfig {

    private String url;

    private String password;

    private String userName;

    private String filePath;

    private String branchName;

}
```

This is the bean

The environment change event is calling for all the Microservices and in other ms the configuration is alomsot the same.